# Is copying inside the same S3 bucket optimized?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my PHP application, I want to allow users to upload to temporary path on S3 Bucket, then move the file to final path.
Unfortunately, S3 does not support moving files directly. You should copy the file and then delete it.

I'd like to know how copying inside the same bucket is handled internally in S3. 
Does S3 actually copy file, or only creates metadata for the new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in Amazon S3 are immutable. It makes a copy of the file.

Comment: So it takes the same amount of time for copying, regardless of source/dest bucket?

Comment: Copying to a bucket in a different region will take longer due to network latency. I haven't tested the speed of copying between buckets vs within a bucket. If you do so, let us know what you find!

Comment: I tried moving a 1GB file to another directory on management console. It was fast, but required several seconds to complete, and progress bar was shown. So I guess you are correct.